# how to build multiple marker with different colours by using flutter table_calendar?

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm new to flutter, learning from [table_calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar) sample code, i'm trying to modify 'Widget _buildTableCalendarWithBuilders' so that it can print multiple markers with different colours, can someone show me the right way?

result i need is when 'Apple' is found in string, print a red dot. when 'Orange' is found in string, print a black dot, if both exist, the date box should have red and black dot.

below is my code

```
        markersBuilder: (context, date, events, holidays) {
          final children = <Widget>[];

          String checkString = events.toString();
          if (checkString.contains('Apple')) {
            children.add(
              Positioned(
                right: 1,
                bottom: 1,
                child: _buildEventsMarker2(date, events, Colors.red),
              ),
            );
          }

          if (checkString.contains('Orange')) {
            children.add(
              Positioned(
                right: 1,
                bottom: 1,
                child: _buildEventsMarker2(date, events, Colors.black),
              ),
            );
          }

          if (holidays.isNotEmpty) {
            children.add(
              Positioned(
                right: -2,
                top: -2,
                child: _buildHolidaysMarker(),
              ),
            );
          }

          return children;
        }
```

my new widget

```
  Widget _buildEventsMarker2(DateTime date, List events, markerColors) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: markerColors,
      ),
      width: 10.0,
      height: 10.0,
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hello, something new about it ?

Comment: Did you find any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two ways to change the colors of the markers.

the first was answered by fabianogadenz here: [github link](https://github.com/aleksanderwozniak/table_calendar/issues/64)

And the second way, I wanted to toggle the marker color when selecting a day with an event. So I stored the selectedDay in a varaible:

```
DateTime? selectedDay;
    
TableCalendar(
  onDaySelected: (a, b) {
    setState(() {
      selectedDay = a;
    });
  },
)
```

then I just compared it with the event map date using the calendarBuilder(singleMarkerBuilder):

```
final map = <DateTime, List<String>>{
  DateTime.utc(2021, 9, 2): [
    'Event A',
    'Event B',
  ],
  DateTime.utc(2021, 9, 3): [
    "Event C",
  ],
};

TableCalendar(
  calendarBuilders: CalendarBuilders(
    singleMarkerBuilder: (context, date, _) {
      return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          color: date == selectedDay ? Colors.white : Colors.black), //Change color
          width: 5.0,
          height: 5.0,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1.5),
      );
    },
  ),
)
```

[Result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7uSO.gif)

Comment: It works for me but I think there is a problem in the snippet:

1. it missed a closing parenthesis
2. width, height, margin should be the properties of the Container instead of BoxDecoration?

Answer (score 6):

You can make multi marker by below code. It may be vertical or horizontal list builder:

```
calendarBuilders: CalendarBuilders(
                            markerBuilder: (BuildContext context, date, events) {
                              if (events.isEmpty) return SizedBox();
                              return ListView.builder(
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                  itemCount: events.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                    return Container(
                                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
                                      child: Container(
                                        // height: 7,
                                        width: 5,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                            color: Colors.primaries[
                                                Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)]),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  });
                            },
                          ),
```

Comment: it throws an error as - type '(BuildContext, DateTime, List<MeetingEventModel>) => Widget' is not a subtype of type '((BuildContext, DateTime, List<dynamic>) => Widget?)?', I did same code as you did

Answer (score 1):

You can add this in CalendarStyle:

markerDecoration: const BoxDecoration(
color: Colors.black,
shape: BoxShape.circle,
),

we have more option if you need to modify event marker:

```
this.markersAlignment = Alignment.bottomCenter,
this.markersMaxCount = 4,
this.markersOffset = const PositionedOffset(),
this.markerDecoration = const BoxDecoration(
  color: const Color(0xFF263238),
  shape: BoxShape.circle,
),
```